# Is there something wrong with this while-loop?

Tags: python, graph

When I execute this code, it prints 'Constructed', meaning it executed Trie Construction - then my terminal outputs nothing, it doesn't return or print any error, it's just blank, as if it's still working on the problem. Is there something wrong with the while loop? Is it that the 'trie' is an external variable?

`trie` is a list of nodes, a class I defined.

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, parent, daughters, edge):
            self.parent = parent
            self.daughters = daughters
            self.edge = edge
            trie.append(self)
            self.index = len(trie) - 1
```

`patterns` is a list of fixed strings.

```
def TrieConstruction(patterns, trie):
    trie.append(node(0, [], 0))
    for pattern in patterns:
        currentNode = trie[0]
        for base in pattern:
            for daughter in currentNode.daughters:
                if base == daughter.edge:
                    currentNode = daughter
                    break
            else:
                trie.append(node(currentNode, [], base))
                currentNode = trie[-1]
    print('Constructed.')
    return

def PrefixTrieMatching(text, trie):
    v = trie[0]
    for index, base in enumerate(text):
        if v.daughters == []:
            pattern_out = []
            climb(v.index)
            return ''.join(pattern_out)
        else:
            for daughter in v.daughters:
                if base == daughter.edge:
                    v = daughter
                    break
            else:
                print('No matches found.')
                return

def climb(index):
    if index == 0:
        return
    else:
        pattern_out.append(node.edge)
        climb(trie[index].parent)

def TrieMatching(text, trie):
    while text != []:
        PrefixTrieMatching(text, trie)
        text = text[0:len(text) - 2]
    print('Complete.')
    return
```

---

```
print('Next, we generate a trie with the patterns, and then run the text over the trie to search for matches.')
trie = []
TrieConstruction(patterns, trie)
TrieMatching(text, trie)
```

Comment: "what's wrong with my code" isn't a well-researched question.

Comment: What are you entering as `text`?

Comment: A large fixed string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Disregard my previous answer, if you are entering a string as `text`, it should be:

```
while text != "":
    PrefixTrieMatching(text, trie)
    text = text[0:len(text) - 2]
```

as the `string` would never be an empty list

Comment: Thank you very much. That is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing  more work than needed, just use `while text` which will return `False` only for an empty string and just slice your string slicing two chars from the end at a time:

```
def TrieMatching(text, trie):
    while text:
        PrefixTrieMatching(text, trie)
        text = text[:-2]
```

An empty list, str, dict etc will always evaluate to False so you don't ever need to explicitly check `if my_list != []`, `if my_str != ""`, `if my_list` and `if my_str` etc.. is sufficient.